# How do you calculate the rotational latency of a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

If you know the RPM, then how do you calculate the rotational latency?

Comment: See this set of 6 closely related questions:
http://superuser.com/questions/119446/sectors-and-clusters
http://superuser.com/questions/119051/transfer-time-for-a-file
http://superuser.com/questions/107723/hard-drive-sectors-vs-tracks
http://superuser.com/questions/119048/number-of-tracks
http://superuser.com/questions/119026/rotational-latency
http://superuser.com/questions/119030/bytes-per-track

Comment: And http://superuser.com/questions/120461/transfer-time-of-a-cylinder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(1 / (RPM / 60)) * 0.5 * 1000

Or, in other words:

30000 / RPM

Result in ms.

Comment: That would be the average rotational delay.  The maximum  would be twice that.

Comment: why `0.5 * 1000`?